# Prove that if $ n+m=10^{10}$, then $n$ is divisible by 10 where n and m have same digits in different order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $m$ be a number having the same digits as that of $n$, but arranged in some other order. Prove that if $ n+m=10^{10}$, then $n$ is divisible by 10.

It seems a pretty difficult question and I don't know how to go about solving this. I even tried to google it but didn't find anything. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your hint is: The remainder when a number is divided by 9 only depends on the number's digits, not on their order, and the same is true for the remainder when divided by 3.

Comment: @MJD I am not very familiar with modular congruence but $ 10^{10}$ leaves remainder 1 when divided by 9 so the sum of the remainders of a and b might be 10 which is possible only when both a and b leave remainder 5 each...is that correct?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I didn't make it up, it's from the book "Challenges and thrill of Pre-college Mathematics" and it's a great book with many questions like this. You can also go through some other questions that I have asked if ur interested in them.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The book asked me to prove that n is divisible by 10 and that's what the answer proves. The answer states that "if n does not end with 0" then there are no m and n are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ and $m$ must each have $10$ digits.  If $n$ does not end in $0$, there must be a carry in each of the $10$ positions when adding $n$ and $m$.  Thus except for the last digit where they add to $10$, the corresponding digits of $n$ and $m$ add to $9$.  That is, the sum of all digits of $n$ and $m$ is $9 \times 9 + 10 = 91$.  But that's odd, so it's impossible for $n$ and $m$ to have the same sum of digits.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck only then can they be added up to form $10^{10}$. $10^{10}$ is the first 11 digit number so they cant be greater than 10 digit and 9 (and below) digit nos cant add up to give an 11 digit no.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck:  $10^{10}$ has $11$ digits.  $n$ and $m$ have the same digits, so they must have the same number of digits.  If that is $9$ or less the sum can't have $11$ digits.  If that is $11$ or more the sum will be more than $10^{10}$

Comment: Can you also point out how MJD's comment was used here? I don't get it's significance...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Quite obviously, they can have *at most* 10 digits, not counting leading $0$s. The rest of the argument treats $0$ as a valid digit, including it being a valid *leading* digit.

Comment: MJD s comment wasn't used.  MJD had another approach altogether.

Comment: Why should the fact that the question is from a textbook mean the answer shouldn't be correct?  I don't know if this is the proof the textbook's author had in mind, but it is a correct proof.